# Does DC DC switching converter needs pot readjusting on input voltage change?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have adjusted my LM2596 regulator to 5V output with 16V input. I'm about to change the input to 25V. Will my 5v output stay the same or do I need to adjust the pot again ?

I can't easily test myself because my circuit would need unsolder and resolder to check and tweak.

Thanks

Comment: It all depends where the pot is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potentiometer sets the *output* voltage, which has little or no bearing on the input voltage.  The whole point of a regulator is to ensure the output voltage is a fixed value regardless of the input voltage, as long as it is between the limits of the regulator input.